# two ajax functions in one page?

Tags: ajax

Hey I am trying to run two ajax functions in the same page

One sends the value put into username
the other sends the value put into email, which sends to ajax.php & ajax1.php

below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AjaxFunction(username)
{
var httpxml;
try
{
// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e)
{
// Internet Explorer
try
{
httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e)
{
try
{
httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e)
{  
alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
return false;
}
}
}
 function stateck() 
{
 if(httpxml.readyState==4)
{
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;

}
}

httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
url="ajax.php?value=" + username.value;
httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
httpxml.send(null);

}


 function AjaxFunction(email)
 {
 var httpxml;
 try
 {
 // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
 httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 catch (e)
{
// Internet Explorer
try
{
httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e)
{
try
{
httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e)
{
alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
return false;
}
}
}
function stateck() 
{
if(httpxml.readyState==4)
 {
 document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;

}
}

httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
url1="ajax.php1?value=" + email.value;
httpxml.open("GET",url1,true);
httpxml.send(null);

}
</script>



<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>Username
       <input type="text" name="username" id="username" onBlur="AjaxFunction(username);">
    </label>
  <div id="msg"></div>
  <p>Email 
    <label>
       <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onBlur="email(EMAIL);">
  </label>  
   <div id="msg1"></div>
   <p>
     <label>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
    </label>
</form>
```

The response text should then be put into div tags (msg & msg1)

Thanks

Comment: what exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax), it will greatly reduce the complexity of your page and provide a nice API for browser abstraction. I can already see cross browser issues.

Comment: Yeh I have already looked into that. The code above "just" works...when i have got it working fully I will clean it up and fix problems

ta

Answer (score 0):

Another if statement that you should probably add to "if (httpxml.readyState == 4)" is "if (httpxml.status == 200)". This makes sure that there weren't any problems server side. Calling both of the requests the same thing is dangerous because any changes made to one can overwrite the other.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to avoid duplicate code? Create a third function that creates the httpxml object and pass it to the first two.

```
httpxml = createAjax();
AjaxFunction(httpxml, username);
```